# Unable to locate the model after upgrate

Tags: php, codeigniter

i started a website using codeigniter 3 -dev about couple of month ago , today i've upgrade it to latest version on github .... it works fine on localhost but when i upload it on server it couldn't find the models !!

```
http://epatil.com/ci_test
```

my only controller :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('test');
        $this->test->echo_print();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

my test.php model

```
<?php
class test extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();  
  }

  function echo_print(){
      echo 1234;
  }


}
```

her eis the result :

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: Test
```

**btw  changing it's name to Test wouldn't help and it used to work fine with lowercase before upgrade**

Comment: try to change model class "test" to "Test"

Comment: If renaming the class to "Test" doesn't work, try renaming the file, to "Test_model.php", then renaming the class to "Test_model"

Comment: I think its your file name problem. I suggest always keep the file name lowercase. Filename `test.php` and `Test.php` is different at different servers.But at windows they treat them same.

Comment: According to the v3 user guide, models MUST match the class name, whereas in v2 documentation, this isn't required. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: @Craig , thax pleas post your comment as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the version 3 user guide, the class names **MUST** match the file name, whereas this wasn't the case, in version 2.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model